# make rows in linear layout clickable

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

So i have a main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static DBhelper myDB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDB=new DBhelper(this);
        //myDB.access_token(93588930);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.char_layout);
        if(( ll).getChildCount() > 0)
            ( ll).removeAllViews();

        JSONArray chars=myDB.get_all_chars();
        TextView[] tv= new TextView[chars.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
            try {
                tv[i] = new TextView(this);
                JSONObject c = (JSONObject) chars.get(i);
                tv[i].setText(c.getString("name")+"\n"+c.getString("id"));
                ll.addView(tv[i]);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    tools:context="com.jbs.evecompanion.MainActivity"
    android:columnCount = "1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/char_layout"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="stufftocall"/>
</GridLayout>
```

I want to be able to on every row and call a function.
Now, as you can see i set "clickable" and "onclick" for the layout. But this would call the same function now matter which row I click, right?
What I want is to click an each row and call the same function with different parameters depending on what text is set in this row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods.

Create one listener :

```
mListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG,"Clicked on "+v.getTag());
    }
};
```

Assign all textViews one tag and add this listener to each of them :

```
tv[i].setTag(i);
tv[i].setOnClickListener(mListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set `android:onClick="stufftocall"` in your `layout.xml`

set it in your java file like as bellow

Assuming tv[i] is your row.

```
tv[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
       // call your desired method with different values here 

    }
});
```